# Imagecreatefromjpeg show resource error

Tags: php, image, resources

I am trying to use `imagecreatefromjpeg()` function, and create image from url.

I use this test link, with picture for testing, but get this error :

> resource(13) of type (gd)

Here is part of code:

$src= $_POST['src'];

```
                    $targ_w = $targ_h = 160;
                    $jpeg_quality = 90;
                    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );


               $test= imagejpeg($dst_r, '/path/to/file, 90);

                      var_dump( $test) ;
```

Also, try to download picture,store to folder, and then use function from localdirectory, no success...

Comment: You probably have a `var_dump()` somewhere. The message you've provided isn't a error.

Comment: Hi,you are right, but with var_dump , need to get true value, to be sure that function is finish. Find that on php manual, but instead of that,get resource message..

Comment: "True value"? What's that? `imagecreatefromjpeg` creates a resource. It appears to be working fine. If you're just wanting the image data and not trying to modify it, then you're probably after `file_get_contents()` or possibly `curl` depending on your setup.

Comment: Joh,you are right, problem is with imagejpeg ...I will update question...

Comment: John, problem with image/path...Solved,tnx a lot!